# Knockout mapping to JS redundancy issue

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am working with knockout mapping to JS currently and i feel that it is pointless in my current case. Perhaps I am using the wrong approach. I will try to describe the scenario i am facing.

I am well aware that knockout mapping to JS include 'ignore' attribute for ignoring certain data when posting data back to the server. But i am currently facing a scenario where i have 12 data to post back to server and 10 data not to post back to server and I does not feel any benefits knockout mapping toJS may give me in this scenario. Or perhaps i am writing my viewmodel the wrong way.

```js
function TestViewModel() {
  self.A = ko.observable();
  self.B = ko.observable();
  self.C = ko.observable();
  
  self.ABComputed = ko.computed(function() { return self.A() + self.B() });
  
  self.EditButtonVisible = ko.observable(true);
  self.CancelButtonVisible = ko.observable(false);
  
  
  self.OnGetViewModel() = function() {
    $.ajax({
       // ko.mapping.fromJS 
    }
  );

  self.OnUpdateViewModel() = function() {
    $.ajax({
       // ko.mapping.toJS
    })
}
  
ko.applyBindings(new TestViewModel());
```

Comment: It's unclear to me what your actual question is. You already know of the "ignore" feature, so you probably also know about the "include" one, and obviously there's also the option to skip using mapping entirely for one or both of the directions. - If you feel a (function from a) plugin isn't useful, then don't use it :-)

Answer (score 0):

The mapping plugin supports rather precise tuning mechanism. However if your case is simple as you demsontrate in your post, you could also simply grab the values to send to the server, put them in a js object manually and send them using ajax. Nothing stopping you from doing it like that. 
The idea of the mapping plugin is, if the manual approach becomes to cumbersome or errorprone, then use the plugin. For small cases, with exceptional requirements, I wouldnt be surprised if coding the conversion by hand can be more straightforward.
This reasoning goes for either way of the communication (observable to js, js to observables)